# "pause the operation", when copying files

Tags: windows-10-preview

Just something I find myself wondering now and don't want to test it myself...

Does anyone happen to know if I click on the "pause the operation" (pause icon) button on a copying window in Windows (10) Technical Preview, can I then remove the external drives I'm copying from/to, provided I plug them back in and make sure they're both being recognized before I click resume?

Because I'm copying a little over 500gb and it claims it will take a little more than a day, and I'd like to shift my laptop to a different location in about 2hrs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my and OP's experiment, the pause function releases the files and hence one can disconnect the drive involved in the operation. It also works with large files and networked storage.

This feature is first introduced in Win 8. More on that can be found in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/492487/can-i-disconnect-a-usb-drive-while-copying-is-paused-in-windows-8) superuser thread.

Comment: Well so far so good. It still says paused after I safely removed the drives. I'll update you when I plug back in and attempt to resume the transfer.

Comment: Great, let me know the results and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Heh. I pushed my luck even further, putting my computer into hibernate while moving it. Upon setting it back up again the transfer did actually just continue as normal. It's quite amazing really.

Comment: That is great! I have to test it on Windows 8.1 too. BTW, did the pause happen in the middle of a (relatively) big file beimg copied or after one file and before the other starts?

Comment: Actually I can't remember. Probably at the end of a large file and before another because it was 'pausing' for quite a long time (5 or so minutes) before it said 'paused'.